Python c_types libc bind method Wrong Answer
I am trying to create my own http server without using any low-level builtin library except ctypes but things are going terribly wrong.
My configuration is correct: IP address is correct, port is available,  I have root privileges, using AF_INET (IPV4 connection) tcp_protocol with sock stream.
My config file includes:
{
    "ipv4_connection" : 2,
    "available_port" : 8081,
    "host_address" : [127, 0, 0, 1],
    "sock_stream" : 1,
    "tcp_protocol" : 0
}

I have created a ctype socket object using ctypes.Structure and everything looks good:
class SocketDeclaration(ctypes.Structure):
    """
        -- load this instance when you have to bind the socket to the given address !
    """
    _fields_ = [
        ('sin_family', ctypes.c_short),
        ('sin_port', ctypes.c_ushort),
        ('sin_addr', ctypes.c_ubyte * 4)
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = ConfigurationFetcher()
        self.sin_family = ctypes.c_short(self.config.ipv4_connection)
        self.sin_port = ctypes.c_ushort((self.config.available_port >> 8) | (self.config.available_port << 8))
        self.sin_addr = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 4)(*self.config.host_address)

The issue here is that despite getting the wrong answer from this call of bind
result = self.libc_object.bind(socket_object, instance_reference, instance_size)

from a method to handle errors gracefully being called as:
# Binding Socket to the Address
socket_instance = SocketDeclaration()
_ = self.bind_socket(new_socket, ctypes.byref(socket_instance), ctypes.sizeof(socket_instance))

it doesn't set the errorno value to -1. My exception object says "unable to bind ; Code = success" - why?
For further clarification the address sin_address is a reference to the object and not values, socket file descriptor returns 3 which is a valid response. I know syntax and just unable to figure about what is wrong.
strace shows that I have some kind of invalid argument as sin_addr but after reading a lot of documentation I just end up asking for the solution from any expert.
Any kind of help would be appreciated !
I literally tried everything; from changing ports to changing address! My machine is Kali kernal 6.10.11-amd64. I studied documentation from 5 sources including Python documentation, IBM, Stackoverflow, Chatgpt, Meta ai and it doesn't work!

[SO]: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Check [SO]: How do I ask a good question? or
[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))
for more asking related details.
Also, [JonSkeet.CodeBlog]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION might be a good point to start. Share all the code not just scattered parts. That's the 1st thing.

Check [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) for a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions). Also why using CTypes instead of https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html? Looks like an XY Problem to me.

"it doesn't set the errorno value to -1". I assume there's a typo. Also what makes you think that errno should be set to -1?

Are you setting use_errno=True in your CDLL load of libc and ctypes.get_errno()?  Make a [mcve].

@CristiFati ; Thank you very much ! English is not native to me and trying to be good at it will take some tiime. i'll make sure next time i format code as you did !

@Mark Tolonen Thank you setting up that use_errno = True works ; It fixed the errorno issue as it now updates itself with inner method operation result code instead of Method execution ! Now it says Invalid argument. Let me just try to debug it and i'll come back for more !
